# gdb 8.1-4 breaks with libbabeltrace-ctf on debian

Tags: dependencies, gdb, debian

Recently I started learning arm toolchain on my Debian Buster and installed gcc-arm-none-eabi.At that gdb was already installed.When I tried to install gdb-arm-none-eabi it redirects me to gdb-multiarch and said that gdb-multiarch 8.1-4 is already installed.Package has a dependency libbabeltrace1 which is also present at:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/libbabeltrace-ctf1_1.5.1-1_i386.deb
```

But I can't start neither gdb nor gdb-multiarch because it gives error:

```
gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libbabeltrace-ctf.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I realize that it can be related with my PATH but it is unclear how to make the dependency visible for gdb.Give advice please.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I purged gdb-multiarch package, then installed new version of libbabeltrace-ctf* with apt and again installed gdb-multiarch.Happens to be that my old dependency libbabeltrace-ctf was incompatible.